# Number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $\;gcd(a,b)=x \quad (1\leq a,b\leq N)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The above problem was encountered in programming competition. I don't know how to solve it. I tried to think using sieve but it won't consider all pair and brute forcing all pairs is not optimal.

Can anyone give idea of the solution?
Consider $\;N\leq 10^5.$

Comment: Hint: $a=mx$ and $b=nx$ where $(m,n)$ coprime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a comment by @karakfa suggests, we need to count the number of relatively prime pairs in $a,b\leq N/x$.

From my answer to this question in MO; [Probability that two numbers are relatively prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97041/what-is-the-probability-that-two-numbers-are-relatively-prime/97047#97047)

It may be useful to have a list of $\{\mu(n): 1\leq n\leq N\}$ where $\mu(n)$ is the [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Then we can use
$$
\sum_{a,b\leq N/x, \ (a,b)=1} 1 = \sum_{a,b\leq N/x}\sum_{d|a,d|b} \mu(d)=\sum_{d\leq N/x} \mu(d)\sum_{a,b\leq N/(xd)}1=\sum_{d\leq N/x} \mu(d)\left\lfloor \frac N{xd}\right\rfloor^2.
$$

Comment: I do not know what is mobius function. I will study it next. Can you check my answer which I understood from comment.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, that is also what I use too.

Answer (score 1):

I got the approach after hint of [karakfa](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/14900/karakfa). I think it will work like this. We will  first find the numbers which are coprime to n for all $n<=N$ which is $\phi(n)$. To get all pairs $(a,b)$ where $1<=a,b<=N$ whose gcd is x, we can multiply all the pair whose $gcd$ is 1 to x which results in gcd x keeping in mind that it doesn't exeeds $N$ which is managable.

In short,
If $(m,n)$ are co-prime, $gcd(x*m,x*n)=x$